# Sony Xperia Tipo not recognizing SD memory card

Tags: external-sd, sony-xperia-tipo

I have installed an 8GB SD memory card in my Sony Xperia Tipo, but the memory card is not being recognized. Has anyone else had this problem with the Sony Xperia Tipo? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: I used Link2SD apps. List2SD apps list out storage device such as internal, SD Card, External SD Card. I try to create location in External card. But I got following failure information.

"Link2SD could not obtain root access. If you have root access make sure you respond 'allow' or 'grant' to the superuser request."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sony unfortunately divided the phone into two drives BEFORE the microsd slot. So the internal drive and the sd drive are already assigned. the external card then formats itself as "ext_card" on the root folder.

i managed to redirect some folders from the internal to the external card via the program "directory bind" (search for it on google, it is not available on the play store). for this to work you need a ROOTED phone. the phone is fairly easy to root via a script (windows). you need to install adb drivers first (if you install sony compagnion, this will install the adb drivers and you have to enable usb debug mode on your tipo before you run the script to root your tipo).

overall this is a little complicated, so i advise you to be an expert user to try this, especially the configuration of "directory bind" is tricky. it would be best if sony "bundled both cards that are installed on the device internally to be just one and then the microsdcard slot would work as desired and could be used to install programs and other stuff much easier.

links:
directory bind: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410262
root tool for tipo: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460

Comment: Actually you can move apps via any dir manager without rooting the phone. The trick is to get the larger apps to work, but you can always move app data to the SD card and leave the app to find it itself. That is just what I discovered. It doesn't work with all the apps, you'll have to modify the app itself to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same phone, I didn't have any problems.

A few possibilities:

- Make sure the card is completely inside the SD card slot.
- Format the card.
- Turn off the phone, take out the battery and pull the SD card out, turn on the phone without the SD card (wait for it to completely load), again turn off the phone, put the SD
  card back in, turn on the phone (wait for it to completely load).
- Remove any widgets that access the card on boot (like gallery widget,
  etc), reboot phone.
- Try another SD card.

Comment: Thanks .. Memory card now got recognized. But I have following trouble.

Setting -> Apps

In this menu I have following tab only.

Download - Internal - Running - All 

But I can't see any tab like external memory card. 
  
Then How Can I move apps Internal Memory card to External Memory card?

Comment: @ashokhein There is no external memory tab. However, you should be able to move it by selecting the app and clicking on the "move to internal storage" button.

Comment: Ya.. of course. But my question how can I move internal storage to External storage. Can I do manually when I connect to PC using USB?

Comment: Please help me :( (headbang)

Comment: I don't think it's possible with our phone, you'll have to partition the SD card to be able to store apps on it.